# How to execute Android 2.3 Source code?

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded the Android 2.3 source code. My question is how can i execute individual code from that source code?
can any one help me....?

Thanks and Regards
Shiva

Comment: shiva explain your question clearly you have the android 2.3 os's Source code and you want to run a part of that code am i right?

Comment: yes karthik. I want to execute Browser Code.

Comment: means that you want to create a browser similar to android browser right?

Comment: actually the kernel files are developed on linux compiled c language i think so so i think you cannot use them in android instead you can use the webview and few other controls present in android for developing your own browser

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article which shows how to build the Android source and deploy it:
http://www.cianer.com/androidg1/28-building-android-kernel-images

Comment: For future answers, please try to write a fuller and more complete answer by itself, and only provide links to external material as reference or additional information. Links which mostly contain just a link and not much else has a high chance of falling prey to linkrot, in which case the external material goes offline and thus your answer becomes unusable.